# How can I measure the CDN hit rate of a CSS file?

Tags: javascript, performance, cdn, webfonts, font-awesome

I'm serving a webfont from [a CDN](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/#fontawesome_tab). I want to know the percentage of visitors that already have the file cached locally.

Is there a way to measure this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [link.onLoad event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Stylesheet_load_events) and the [Navigation Timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Navigation_timing) to calculate how long it takes each CSS file to load. Both API's are supported on modern browsers.

If you need insight into the hit rate of older browsers[0] you could use an `<img>` tag with the `src` set to your css. Then measure the time in the `onerror` event, which is fired when the browser loads the file and figures out it's not actually an image. This technique is [described here](http://www.backalleycoder.com/2011/03/20/link-tag-css-stylesheet-load-event/).

The most thorough solution would be to A/B test both options with JavaScript to see which one loads faster on average[1] for your specific visitors.

---

[0] I would guess older browsers would have a lower CDN hit rate simply because their default cache sizes are much smaller.

[1] Standard statistical disclaimers apply, e.g. you may want to optimize for best 95% percentile instead of the best average latency.